# EKEventStore.calendars returns non-existing "calendar" object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When obtaining all calendars on IOS5 using

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
NSArray * calendars = [eventStore calendars];
```

there is a calendar named "calendar" returned. This calendar is not existing in users calendar list. It's holding this properties:

```
EKCalendar <0x357700> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #882F00;
```

User can store events there. Those events are displayed on the IOS calendar. Does anyone know what kind of calendar this is? Seems to be some sort of default calendar. BTW: Users calendars are all CalDAV based, so this might be the reason for this object.

Answer (score 1):

In code you don't have complete access to all the calendars the user has in its native app.

```
"Event Kit provides limited access to a user’s calendar information. It is not
suitable for implementing a full-featured calendar application."
```

If you want to **edit** an existing event, you'll have no problems:

```
 "You can fetch events based on a date range or a unique identifier,
receive notifications when event records change, and allow users to create
and edit events for any of their calendars. Changes made to events in a
user’s Calendar database with Event Kit are automatically synced with the
appropriate calendar (CalDAV, Exchange, and so on)."
```

If you want to **add** new event, you can only add it to the calendar, that user had selected as the **default calendar** (in settings application).

```
    "Creating and Editing Events

    If the event property is nil when you present the view controller,
the user creates a new event in the default calendar and saves it to
the specified event store.

    If the event property is nil when you present the view controller,
the user creates a new event in the default calendar and saves it to
the specified event store."
```

All quotations from [Event Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/EventKitProgGuide.pdf).

Comment: I have access to all the users calendars using [eventStore calendars]. Issue is: on some devices, I see one calendar **more** than in the calendar application.


You write "In code you don't have complete access to all the calendars the user has in its native app." Thats not the point. See above.

Comment: @Bertl: sorry, missed that iOS5.0 part. My answer is valid for <iOS4.0 and first guess would be, that this 'calendar' calendar is there for compatibility sake. It should be default calendar (as set int settings). To my defence: last revision of EK Programming Guide was made in 2010 :) I didn't find it in documentation but it shold be the same as `defaultCalendarForNewEvents` property.