# iOS EventKit: EKCalendar named "Calendar"? What is it?

Tags: ios, eventkit

When I query the EKCalendars on my iPad via -[EKEventStore calendars], an EKCalendar called "Calendar" is always returned. It has a type of "Local" and never has any events. (Note: the same calendar is also returned via the iOS Simulator on the desktop.)

The Calendar app on my iPad doesn't list this calendar. Should my app? Or should I exclude it from display, like Calendar app?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EKEventStore.calendars returns non-existing "calendar" object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563981/ekeventstore-calendars-returns-non-existing-calendar-object)