# Two "Calendar" entries listed on iPad - can't write to calendar using EventKit

Tags: ios, ios5, xamarin.ios, eventkit

My iOS app integrates with the device's calendar.  On my iPad when I view the calendar app and tap the Calendars button on the top left to choose which calendars to show I see one entry named "Calendar". In my app when I loop through available calendars per the code below "Calendar" is listed twice.  One is CalDAV for the type, the other is Local.  I'm unable to create calendar entries in one of them, I believe the "Local" one, not sure why.

Why do I see "Calendar" listed twice when I do NOT see it listed twice in the iCal app?

```
        public static List<string> Calendars
    {
        get
        {
            var calendars = new List<string>();

            var ekCalendars = EventStore.Calendars;
            if (ekCalendars != null && ekCalendars.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (EKCalendar cal in ekCalendars)
                {
                    if (cal.AllowsContentModifications)
                        calendars.Add(cal.Title);
                }
                calendars.Sort();
            }
            return calendars;
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [EKEventStore.calendars returns non-existing "calendar" object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563981/ekeventstore-calendars-returns-non-existing-calendar-object)

Answer (score 1):

If you have iCloud enabled you will not see the local calendars.

I believe this is by design for the user. When you turn on iCloud it offers to merge your local calendars in to iCloud. Once iCloud is enabled iOS will hide the local calendars, even ones you create programmatically, from the user so they don't create events in a local calendar and then wonder why they rant synching with iCloud.

Check http://www.raywenderlich.com for a decent tutorial in EKVentKit in their book.

But no books or tutorials I've found talk sensibly about creating calendars in iCloud or locally and the problems caused when you turn iCloud on and off...

Comment: I have iCloud enabled but do not use it for Calendar sync and I see this issue on my iPad.

Comment: I've confirmed with the big 'A' that local calendars are not available with iCloud turned on, and that this is by design.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I see "Calendar" listed twice when I do NOT see it listed twice in the iCal app?

FWIW you're [not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626870/ios-eventkit-ekcalendar-named-calendar-what-is-it) looking for an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563981/ekeventstore-calendars-returns-non-existing-calendar-object).

As for seeing it **twice** ? I cannot duplicate this using my own devices (running iOS 5.1), even one without any email address (or calendar) configured. What I get (in iCal) is iCloud (split in **Home** and **Work**) and Other (**Birthdays**) calendars. Maybe that's because I have iCloud enabled ?

Using some quick-n-hackish C# code both **Home** and **Work** are `CalDav` (device only), **Birthdays** is `Birthday` (both device and simulator) and another one, **Calendar** which is `Local` (on both device and simulator) but **not** visible in iCal.

So there's definitively an **extra**, undocumented (so far) `Local` calendar.

Comment: Try debugging so you're iterating the calendars on your iPad and then you may see it.  That's when I see it.  I'm afraid of filtering out the Calendar(Local) one as I don't know it's purpose.  I wonder if it simply represents the users' default calendar selection in the device's Settings?  I'll have to tinker with the device's settings in the calendar area and see what effect that has.

Comment: I already tried this while debugging with the **same** results (i.e. only one **Calendar**-named entry). The *default* calendar is represented by the `DefaultCalandendarForNewEvents` property and (for me) it is set on **Work**, type `CalDav` (default, should be modifiable using **Settings**). I also tried again this morning with an iPad (email enabled) running iOS 5.1 with the **same** results. My initial *guess* was that this *ghost* calendar was used when offline (no iCloud/Caldav access) but switching to airplane mode did not change anything...

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I see this as well.  Details from a debug print:

EKCalendar <0x1aa6b0> {title = Calendar; type = Exchange; allowsModify = YES; color = #0E61B9;},
EKCalendar <0x1aa790> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #F64F00;},

More information:
I have an app that functions like the traditional calendar app and allows you to pick a calendar then shows the entries for that calendar.  From my debugging and using my app the same events occur in both "Calendar" apps.  The "duplicate" calendar is not visible in the Calendar app.  Also the duplicate showed up when I added a GMAIL calendar to my iPhone for testing multiple calendars in my app.  The "duplicate" calendar doesn't appear in the simulator.  I did extensive multiple calendar testing on prior IOS versions and never saw this before ... is it new with IOS 5.1?

I search the IOS Developer Board, only one other posting the same question.  I replied and will let you know here what I find out.

If you are interested ... here is the code to filter it out ...

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
for (EKCalendar *cal in eventStore.calendars) {
    if (cal.type != EKCalendarTypeLocal) {
         // do something
    }
}
```